# Array of colors for products with table association in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There are these three tables in my application:

```
table: products
columns: id, name, price

table: colors
columns: id, name, products_count

table: product_colors
columns: id, product_id, color_id
```

And in my case, a product can have multiple colors. This is the query I'm using to get the products:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.price
FROM products
```

So, how can I get all the colors for a specific product through an array? Something like this:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.price, colors.name color
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_colors ON product_colors.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN colors ON colors.id = product_colors.color_id
```

### What's going on with the above's syntax?

`colors.name` column just retrieves one color.

### In PHP/CodeIgniter I just want to do something this:

**view.php:**

```
<h1><?php echo $product->name; ?></h1>
<div class="colors">
    Colors available:
    <?php foreach ($product->colors as $color) { ?>
        <?php echo $color->name; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Is this possible to perform using native CodeIgniter? I mean, without Doctrine or another ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

The final query would look something like that:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, products.price, GROUP_CONCAT(colors.name ORDER BY colors.name SEPARATOR '+') colors
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_colors ON product_colors.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN colors ON colors.id = product_colors.color_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

Then in your result output:

```
[...]
$colorArray = explode("+", $product->colors); //this is your array of color names.
```

You are able to write this using CodeIgniter's Active Record. However it may cause performance issues on big chunks of data.

Comment: I thought to use GROUP_CONCAT, but at the same time I guessed it isn't  a good practice at all. But if there's no alternative to sculpt this mechanism without any ORM, ok, let's go then. By the way, what's the best alternative to go against performance issues?

Comment: Yes this should do it and no need to do `foreach ($product->colors as $color)` its directly accessible using `$product->colors` just need to split the way it needs to be displayed !!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Actually, I'll need to explode the colors because I will perform some complexes tasks with them. I mean, it's not just disposing or displaying - there are a few things more than this, like JavaScript controls  and actions.

Comment: Here is a 2 varity of same query sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd3e4f/1 go with the one that @Aidas added.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The Aidas' one is the best?

Comment: yes of course his one u should choose !! The other one I added which is for more complex scenario where u need to get the count first and then group. But for ur case its not needed.